# CFMail sending to first recipient of query result only

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

When attempting to send an email to multiple recipients using ColdFusion, only the first row is receiving the email and it seems to be hit three times but only sending once.  This works **but all recipients are visible** and the `cfoutput` is displayed as many times are there are recipients:

```
<cfmail
to = "#ValueList(getEmail.Schd_Email)#"
from="test@test.edu"
subject="This is a Test"
type="HTML"
query="getEmail"
failto="test@test.com">
The location has been moved to <b><cfoutput>#location#</cfoutput></b><br/>
</cfmail>
```

This only sends to the first person listed in the query and the `cfoutput` in the body is still listed as many times as there are recipients.

```
<cfmail
to = "#Schd_Email#;"
from="test@test.edu"
subject="This is a Test"
type="HTML"
query="getEmail"
failto="test@test.com">
The location has been moved to <b><cfoutput>#location#</cfoutput></b><br/>
</cfmail>
```

I can output the query to the page and see all emails listed.  Not sure why the latter does not work.  Any ideas?

Comment: You could also send individually, by `cfloop`'ing through the query, and nesting `cfmail` inside the loop.  FWIW, it worked fine w/CF11. Are there any other variables in the page named `#Schd_Email#`, aside from the query column? What happens if you remove the pound signs, ie `from="Schd_Email"`?

Comment: Ended up using the bcc suggested below with an email being sent to an admin or group while the bcc recipients are the ones who need to receive the email.  That was correct in the recipients must not be visible to each other.  <cfmail
to = 'group@test.com'
bcc = "#ValueList(getEmail.Schd_Email)#"
from="group@test.com"
subject="This is a Test"
type="HTML"
query="getEmail"
failto="group@test.com">
The location has been moved to <b><cfoutput>#loc#</cfoutput></b><br/>
</cfmail>

Comment: Well as Miguel-F mentioned, you should not need ValueList() if you are already using the "query" attribute (and vice versa).

Comment: @Leigh Yes.  All the documentation I have read indicates that.  If I do not have ValueList() it still only sends to the first address in the query.  I did try as you suggested above without the pound signs and it was unsuccessful.  I did not try the <cfloop> route yet since the bcc seems to be working okay.  I will be trying it out to learn how to use it.

Comment: Yes, I was wrong about the pound signs. Not sure what the heck I was thinking, as it just sets the "to" address to  the literal string "Schd_Email". However, as Miguel-F pointed out, what you had originally should work fine. It worked for me w/CF11,0,03,292866, so most likely something is different in your actual code.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use ';' delimiter in valueList(). the default delimiter for valueList() is ','. If you pass delimiter ';' it might work. 
Try this one #ValueList(getEmail.Schd_Email,";")#

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the `query` attribute of the `cfmail` tag you do not need to use the `ValueList()` function.  The `query` attribute handles that functionality for you. It also negates the need for using a delimeter between each of the "to" addressees. It should work like this assuming you have valid email addresses in your query results.

```
<cfmail
    to="#getEmail.Schd_Email#"
    from="test@test.edu"
    subject="This is a Test"
    type="HTML"
    query="getEmail"
    failto="test@test.com">
    <div>The location has been moved to <b><cfoutput>#location#</cfoutput></b></div>
</cfmail>
```

Comment: *do not need to use the ValueList()* True. I could be wrong, but it also sounded like they did not want "to" recipients to be visible to each other. So they might want to use a cfloop with a nested cfmail instead, or maybe use "bcc" rather than "to".

Comment: I never use the query attribute of cfmail but I thought it sent out individual emails to each recipient. Not sure though and cannot test right now.

Comment: Neither do I, but you are right. It does (tested with CF11).

Comment: Thanks for confirming Leigh